# i'm getting crazy trying to upload my app

Tags: iphone, upload, binary, keychain

I'm getting crazy, I was trying to upload with application loader, but i got this error:

'The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate'

then, looking for a solution, some idiot told me that he had the same issue, & he realized that he had 2 keys, & he fixed it removing one of them... Other idiot (me) listened to him & removed one of the keys... Now I lost my key, & I don't know how to recover them!

And the first problem still there...

any help, please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your first problem it is usually just because it hasn't been signed with your distribution key or the key you've used was created for a different project name  (or as I found out recently if you zip the file on a windows machine it will break it too).

To address your second issue, about deleting the key and it now missing this is trivial and nothing to worry about (usually).  I've deleted all my keys many times and reinstalling them is just a case of logging into your provisioning portal and clicking download on the provisioning profile(s)  you need assuming you've created them already.

i.e. you will need a development key associated with the projects named "com.*yourcompany*.*".  *(I believe xcode will now handle this debug team profile automatically for you however I like telling it to use my development key as you know what it's doing and when they need renewing.)*

This is the key you'll use to build your debug and release builds with to run on your local iPhone.

You will also need your distribution key which needs to be explicitly named such as "com.*yourcompanyname*.*yourproductname*". and must match your project's identifier which is found in the project settings->Configuration tab I believe.

Once you have these redownloaded, double click the provisioning files to make sure they're installed.  (The Organizer utility should pop up showing which profiles are available).  You can now check your project settings (make sure you have distribution build selected at the top left.   If you only have Debug/Release you need to make the distribution build 
target by duplicating Release), and look at the codesigning part.

The codesigning section should show which provisioning profile it's using so should have your distribution key specified here.  If it doesn't, open up the drop down to select the new one you've just installed.  If that doesn't appear (or is greyed out) it's because the ID name in your project hasn't matched the key ID name.

If you've done this previously and it's still not working it might be something else but thought it best covering the usual culprits first.

(Also would be good to highlight which xcode version you're using as I've not tried Xcode 4 which may have a different workflow)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the certificates (except your original key) from Apple's developer portal.

Code singing can be painful but does work in the end (usually). I usually try the following:

- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Clean, exit Xcode, rebuild
- Clean, in the Finder go and delete all intermediate files, rebuild

You can also just resign archives in the Organizer panel in Xcode. That may be quicker but I'm not sure whether it's more or less effective.

Answer (score 0):

You may generate a new distribution public/private keypair and create a new distribution identity (i.e. X.509 certificate). Then just re-sign your application with the new distribution identity and retry your upload.  Just revoke your existing distribution certiciate first in the provisioning portal.